# Why is my minitest.rake running twice when I enter rake into terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake, minitest

I created a minitest.rake, as per ryan bates railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/327-minitest-with-rails).

When I run rake in the terminal, the test runs, and then runs again before resetting the command line.

```
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new(:test => "db:test:prepare") do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
end

task default: :test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suppose you already have a task with such a name defined. If you define a new task with the same name it is appended to already existing one.

What if you remove or comment out this code and do `rake -T`, will `test` task be there?

Comment: How can I find that out? This is the only file in my lib/tasks dir.

Comment: If you are using it in rails it already has `test` task. What if you remove or comment out your task code and do `rake -T`, will `test` task be there?

Comment: It is there. Is it alright if I continue to use 'rake test' and remove my code completely?

Comment: Well, if you are happy with your testing now, this is OK. If you still want to try minitest unfortunately I do not have an answer. The railscast is paid, so I do not know how Ryan Bates solves the issue.

Comment: In the episode, he generates an app, passing in '-T' to skip the test files. To go along with the episode, I deleted all of the contents of my generated "test folder". The code in my original post is exactly what the railscast instructed to use in the lib/tasks folder. My guess is the default 'rake test' is excluded as well when running 'rails new -T'.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just checked, `rails new -T` generates a slightly different `config/application.rb` where all the rails components are loaded, but `rails/test_unit/railties` is skipped, so this rake task is absent.

Answer (score 3):

Just rename your rake file with a unique name; ex. `mintest1.rake`.

I had the same issue when I named my rake file `paperclip.rake`. What ever I defined in that rake file, it got executed twice. I assume this is because the Paperclip gem already defines a rake file `paperclip.rake`. So I just renamed my `paperclip.rake` file to `pc.rake` and it worked for me.

Comment: exactly the same issue with paperclip tasks; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rake test:single TEST=path/to/test.rb`?

If I were to drop :single then it would run twice.